# How would I automatically detect a user's location and save in db?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I currently have a Tracker app and I would like to have Rails detect a users's location (register in my app) by the IP address

and save `Latitude`,`Longitude` like [iplocation site](http://www.iplocation.ne).

user Model contain `id`, `username`,`email`,`password`,`Latitude`,`Latitude`

Comment: you have to send this information from client (your tracker app)

Comment: need updated location when visit site?

Comment: This sample  https://jsfiddle.net/deepumohanp/a4g2J/ will give the lat ,long of the client. You want the location by IP address ?

Comment: Thanks @praaveen i need automatically save it .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the user's ip address into an API that maps ip's to a location.

One way to do this is to create a ruby module in lib that has a method that takes in an ip address and sends a request to the API to get a location.

```
module Location
  require 'net/http'
  require 'json'

  def get_location ip_address
    location = Net::HTTP.get(URI("https://ipapi.co/#{ip_address}/json/"))
    JSON.parse(location)
  end

  module_function :get_location
end
```

The JSON that is returned includes longitude and latitude.

Then you can call this method from your Users controller

```
require 'location'

class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @user = User.new(params.require(:user).permit(:longitude, :latitude))
    location = get_user_location

    @user.longitude = location["longitude"]
    @user.latitude = location["latitude"]

    if @user.save
      # Do something
    else
      # Do somehting else
    end
  end

  private

  def get_user_location
    ip_address = request.remote_ip
    Location.get_location ip_address
  end
end
```

Note: The ip_address won't work locally, so to test it out you'll have to hard code in an ip address instead of calling request.remote_ip (ie ip_address = "8.8.8.8").

EDIT:
Updating the users location would require basically the same logic as setting it during the create action. So, I would recommend just extracting all of the logic into the module...something like this

```
module Location
  require 'net/http'
  require 'json'

  def get_location ip_address
    location = Net::HTTP.get(URI("https://ipapi.co/#{ip_address}/json/"))
    JSON.parse(location)
  end

  def set_location user ip_address
    location = get_location ip_address
    user.longitude = location["longitude"]
    user.latitude = location["latitude"]
    user.save
  end

  module_function :set_location
end
```

This will allow you to get rid of all of the location logic in the users controller and then reuse the set_location method throughout your controllers.

Comment: Thanks @Mark but can help me example of `update_location` method

Comment: Updated with an example!

Answer (score 1):

Script form anujay - jsfiddle  (http://jsfiddle.net/anujay0402/TPhUC/)

HTML

```
<h3>Client side IP geolocation using</h3>
<hr/>
<div id="ip"></div>
<div id="address"></div>
<hr/>Full response: <pre id="details"></pre>
```

Script

```
$.get("http://ipinfo.io", function (response) {
    $("#ip").html("IP: " + response.ip);
    $("#address").html("Location: " + response.city + ", " + response.region + "," + response.country );
    $("#details").html(JSON.stringify(response, null, 4));
}, "jsonp");
```

output

```
Client side IP geolocation using
IP: 45.11.14.1
Location: Chennai, Tamil Nadu,IN
Full response:
{
    "ip": "45.11.14.1",
    "hostname": "45.11.14.1.live.vodafone.in",
    "city": "Chennai",
    "region": "Tamil Nadu",
    "country": "IN",
    "loc": "13.03,80.23",
    "postal": "009144",
    "org": "AS38266 Vodafone Essar Ltd., Telecommunication - Value Added Services,"
}
```

Comment: how to save in my db;

Comment: @Sdadad With the help of ajax call. sample is here http://jsfiddle.net/ddtxra/60wme3pf/

Comment: Thanks @praaveen but not can save it

Comment: @Sdadad can I have more info.

Answer (score 0):

The [Devise gem](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) actually allows you to capture IP address if you don't want to mess with the session info.

Check out Devise's trackable feature [here](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Trackable).

Comment: Thanks @Chiperific i not use  `Devise gem`

Comment: Right, but you could review their code and see how they are doing it.